# Apache camel and SQS Extended Client Library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

So. As you know AWS Simple Queue Service has some limitation on a message's size. There is also a [library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib) called Extended Client Library that help us to avoid this limitation by using S3 bucket storage. And I also use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html) to manage my queues.

I think I just misunderstand the conception, but I have the problem to make Apache Camel And Extended SQS Library work together.

So first of all I defined a new route

```
from("aws-sqs://queue?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient" +
            "&maxMessagesPerPoll=10" +
            "&deleteAfterRead=false" +
            "&concurrentConsumers=10" +
            "&attributeNames=All" +
            "&messageAttributeNames=All"
        ).log(body());
```

`sqsClient` is defined inside a `camel-context.xml`

```
    <bean name="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="${access.key}"/>
            <constructor-arg value="${secret.key}"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="region" ref="awsRegion"/>
</bean>
```

And this point there is no problem dealing with messages up to 256 kb.

Let's go further. The Extended SQS Library detects if the message is bigger 256 kb and makes a reference to the file inside S3 storage. And simple fetchs it later.

> ["com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.MessageS3Pointer",{"s3BucketName":"test-bucket-ascelhem","s3Key":"b022dfd8-ed40-4213-a41e-5a0e82090ef4"}]

There are some pre-configuration before the client is able to use it:

First of all we set the SQS extended client configuration with large payload support enabled.

```
ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfig = new ExtendedClientConfiguration().withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(s3, s3BucketName);
```

And finally

```
AmazonSQS sqsExtended = new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(new AmazonSQSClient(credentials), extendedClientConfig);
        Region sqsRegion = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1);
        sqsExtended.setRegion(sqsRegion);
```

So can I configure it via Spring DSL or should I fetch the message and inside a processor get the message body?

Next, it's a method that help us to fetch message body.

```
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(myQueueUrl);
    List<Message> messages = sqsExtended.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
```

Does the Apache camel overrides somehow getMessage? Because inside the app we can get message body by calling method `body()`.

And if there is an opportunity to configure Apache Camel in such way so that it can handle very-big-messages, the line `new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
                .withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(s3, s3BucketName);` confused me a lot because I have no idea how to call static method inside xml file.

And finally the line

```
<bean name="sqsClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsyncClient">
```

Here we use `AmazonSQSAsyncClient`, but as I mentioned earlier, the Extended Client Library initializes via `AmazonSQS` ... interface? So, I'm totally trapped.

Also I've fount the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/s3-messages.html) of using this library. It might be helpful for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best solution I've found was to create a process that first fetch the message body fro s3 object and do somethings with it.